# Automatic profiling visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, profiling

Is there a way to do automatic profiling in visual studio 2008?

I know how the profiling works both from the command line and using the GUI in VS08.

What I want to accomplish:
After my nightly build I want to complete some profiling (instrumental) to see if some functions (will most likely always be the same) have changed in some negative way (or positive of course).

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find a solution to my problem.

I found you that it is possible to profile Unit Tests from the command line so that will be the solution to my problem.